# Request ideas- How to sort a 2d array with many rows and 3 columns, maintaining data rows

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I've made progress in scanning an MIT Meep control file into tokens by character location. I now have an nx3 array of integers with the 3 columns identifying:

- character location
- token identifier
- token length

Except they are in "found" order, not in input order. I note that the character location can become very large, easily into the 10's of thousands (that is, thousands of rows) while the token identifier and token length are each below one hundred.

I need to sort my nx3 array by character location in increasing order without loosing the other two columns. I have researched and the answer seems to be to write some code implementing a bubble sort or other similar algorithm.

Is there a function is C++ that can sort the entries in the first column of my array without loosing the associated row entries? A little bit of my test control file caused generation of an array that looks like this:

```
380  2  1
401  2  1
441  2  1
442  2  1
178  4  13
178  18  7
0  26  5
59  26  5
218  26  5
330  26  5
382  26  5
23  32  5
80  32  5
142  32  5
238  32  5
256  32  5
353  32  5
74  38  5
232  38  5
347  38  5
403  44  4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a day trying to build a structure. Unfortunately my c++ knowledge - experience is not up to the task. I could not get anything to compile. So I went the old Fortran way and got this code to work and accomplish what I need.

Code bloat? Most likely from the headers. Run time? Loops through the whole long data stream more than twice. Oh well, it works but if I could make a structure work I'd change it, or at least do a benchmark.

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <sstream>      // std::istringstream
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>      // sprintf
using namespace std;

int main() {

std::vector<std::string> data(512);
int length = 8;
size_t arat[length];
int arid[length];
int arlen[length];
int n ;
int i ;
char buffer [17];

arat[0]=     0 ; arid[0] = 1;  arlen[0] = 1;
arat[1]=   418 ; arid[1] = 1;  arlen[1] = 1;
arat[2]=    57 ; arid[2] = 2;  arlen[2] = 1;
arat[3]=   442 ; arid[3] = 2;  arlen[3] = 91;
arat[4]=   178 ; arid[4] = 1;  arlen[4] = 1;
arat[5]= 178632 ; arid[5] =180;  arlen[5] = 226;
arat[6]=     0 ; arid[6] =26;  arlen[6] = 5;
arat[7]=    59 ; arid[7] =26;  arlen[7] = 5;
cout << '\n';
i = 0; 
while(i<length){
n=sprintf (buffer," %*lu  %*d  %*d", 6,arat[i], 3,arid[i], 3,arlen[i]);
if(n < 0) break;
cout << buffer ; data[i] = buffer; cout << data[i] <<'\n'; i++;}
cout << '\n';
std::sort (data.begin(), data.begin()+8); // sort data 0 thru 7, not 8.

i = 0;
while (i < length) {cout << data[i] << '\n';i++;}

cout << '\n';
i = 0;
while (i < length) {
std::istringstream iss (data[i]);
iss >> arat[i] ;        // pick off the first number
iss >> arid[i] ;        // pick off the next number
iss >> arlen[i] ;       // pick off the next number after that.
cout << " size_t value of arat[i] = "<< arat[i] << " int arid[i] = "<<arid[i]
    << " int arlen[i] "<< arlen[i]<<'\n';
 i++; }
cout << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

So this is not really the answer I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility could be to define your rows as structs {a,b,c}, compare the 'a' fields and then use the compiler's struct assignment feature to swap the structs (in effect swapping the rows).

```
typedef struct ROW {
    int a, b, c;
};
struct ROW A, B;
...
if (A.a > B.a) {
    struct ROW tmp = A; A = B; B = tmp;
}
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap each entry in a structure with three fields and define a comparison that is based on the value of the first field:

```
struct Entry {
    int loc, ident, length;
    Entry(int loc, int ident, int length)
      : loc(loc), ident(ident), length(length)
    {}

    bool operator<(const Entry& other) const {
        return loc < other.loc;
    }
};
```

After that you can just use the standard `sort` function

```
std::vector<Entry> data;
// ... fill the vector ...
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

If instead the array is already given as `int data[][3]` things are more annoying, I'd probably go for manually inlining a shell-metzener sort:

```
for (int m=n>>1; m>0; m>>=1) {
    for (int j=0; j<n-m; j++) {
        for (int i=j; i>=0 && data[i][0]>data[i+m][0]; i-=m) {
            std::swap(data[i][0], data[i+m][0]);
            std::swap(data[i][1], data[i+m][1]);
            std::swap(data[i][2], data[i+m][2]);
        }
    }
}
```

It's a decent sort algorithm for the general case and it's just three lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct row_head 
{
int char_loc;
int token_index;
};

vector<row_head> heads;
vector<int> token_id;
vector<int> token_length;
```

The variable heads used for sorting and would use corresponding index to access the data. For example, in the above dataset first 5 elements are considered simplicity.
Before Sorting:

```
{380,0}  5 1

{401,1}  8  1

{441,2}  9  1

{442 ,3} 10  2

{178 ,4} 4  1
```

After sorting data in heads would look like this:

```
{178,4}

{380,0}

{401,1}

{441,2}

{442,3}
```

Actual token data remains the same:

```
5  1

8  1

9  1

10  2

4  1
```

Comment: Does this mean that as I find the tokens, I should store the char_loc; and the token_index; in a vector row_heads, and the token_id and token length in two other vectors, instead of storing them all in an nx3 int array? That seems plausible so all I really need is a working knowledge of:  
typedef struct row_head {
int char_loc;
int token_index;
};  I need to look for that.

Comment: You can have two nx2 arrays, first array holds character location and token index. The second array can hold token id and token length.